# Debugging Cordova app on iOS Device: Safari crashes when closing app or debugger

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, safari

I have a Cordova 4.3.0 app that I'm trying to debug with desktop Safari's web inspector.  I can connect and debug fine, but if I quit the app (dismiss from multitasking view, or stop via XCode), Safari crashes.  If I try to close the debugging window in Safari instead, Safari crashes.  I don't have this issue when debugging the same app in the emulator, only when debugging on device.

I'm not setting any debugger breakpoints; I'm using Safari to watch the console output, and to occasionally inspect the web app.

Is this a known issue?  Anything I need to do to safely close the debugging session?

Answer (score 0):

You should give [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) a try. It's nearly the best debugger for Cordova/Phonegap apps i've ever seen.

Hope that i helped you! :-)

Comment: Looks like GapDebug has been discontinued: https://www.genuitec.com/discontinue-development-of-gapdebug/

Comment: Jep, it did. Instead i recommed to use safari developer tools